# Font sizes rendering smaller on github pages. Why?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

local version

[image: local version]

The font sizes on the github pages version of my site: https://shubanshii.github.io/Vocabulary-Cards-CSS/html/index.html are smaller than on my local machine (in the picture).

The font family is correct on both.

Even when I remove the code that actually affects the font, it's still different on both.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  }
  #title {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #input,
    p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  }
```

I do have the meta tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Probably you set your browser to zoom out for github or zoom in on your local development environment.

Comment: hahahaha omg.  that's totally it.  you nailed it.  thanks m8.

Comment: That was quite easy to spot, no way the font on your local environment is 20px, it's much bigger.